# I2C devices not detected

Tags: raspbian, i2c

I'm running raspbian on my pi and followed [this](http://www.abelectronics.co.uk/i2c-raspbian-wheezy/info.aspx) tutorial to get the i2c going. i2cdetect -y 1 used to detect my i2c devices but doesn't anymore. The sensor is connected like this:
[image]

Could this be a software issue?

Comment: Has this been solved? If so, please mark the answer that fixed it as such. We're trying to get this site up to par and the Q:A ratio is really bad. Thanks!

Comment: What kernel are you using? I found that I have to `rmmod i2c_bcm2708; modprobe i2c_bcm2708` with kernel 3.10.28, otherwise i2cdetect doesn't find anything. It worked fine with the 3.6 kernel.

Comment: the tip from elmicha (rmmod i2c_bcm2708; modprobe i2c_bcm2708) is still valid on a 4.1.15 kernel.

Answer (score 3):

> Could this be a software issue?

If `lsmod | grep i2c` shows `i2c-dev` is loaded and you have the device wired as shown, it's pretty unlikely.

I've only used 3.3 V things, but I seem to recall reading certain limitations WRT to 5 V ones; you might want to consider that since you used *devices* plural.

Comment: i2c_dev and i2c_bcm2708 is the output. Currently I only have one device at a time attached.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure,

You have connected VCC to 5v,
SDA to SDA, SCL to SCL and GND to GN.

First of all, what do you see when you type `i2cdetect -y 1` (assuming you have 2nd version of Raspberry Pi, else type `i2cdetect -y 0`) ?

Do you see an empty address i2c table ?

If yes, then,
According to the documentation [here](http://www.robot-electronics.co.uk/htm/srf02tech.htm)

> "There are two operating modes for the SRF02. I2C mode and Serial
>   Mode. This is set with the Mode pin, connected to 0v Ground for Serial
>   Mode and left unconnected (or tied to +5v Vcc) for I2C Mode. "

Have you tried to connect the mode pin to +5volts yet ?

Answer (score 0):

All the device not work directly on raspberry pi I2c bus without change, maybe you can try to add/remove the pull-up resistor.

Are you sure the device is adapted to raspberry pi spec ?

sometime you need to remove the pull-up resistor from the device (if you device is for arduino) because the raspberry have pull-up (1k8) integrated and the arduino not.

Comment: http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Grove_-_I2C_Motor_Driver_V1.3 http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.141/spring2011/pub/labs/LocalNavigation/docs/SRF02-I2CTechSpecs.pdf These are the devices I tried to connect. Do they need the pull-up resistors?